# Insert a multiple constant value after header in csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

Is it possible to insert 9 new lines of Constant Value("AA") in a CSV starting from the 2nd row? I need to insert the "AA" at the top 9 rows(after the header).

**Original CSV look like this:**

```
LEID,MI_RL,TOTDEPTH, INSERTED
07JW01,51,120,2/10/2014 10:37
DD18006,40,10,20/10/2018 16:55
```

**Final CSV should Look like this:**

```
LEID,MI_RL,TOTDEPTH, INSERTED
AA,AA,AA,AA
AA,AA,AA,AA
AA,AA,AA,AA
AA,AA,AA,AA
AA,AA,AA,AA
AA,AA,AA,AA
AA,AA,AA,AA
AA,AA,AA,AA
AA,AA,AA,AA
07JW01,51,120,2/10/2014 10:37
DD18006,40,10,20/10/2018 16:55
```

**Problem 1**

How could I insert  data from the second column, "AA" from line 2 to 9, and automatically send all other data  down one line? Also, I want the code dynamic as I just wanted to tell the  starting index and ending index and it add the constant value between those two indexes?

**Problem 2**

The other issue is that every CSV has a different number of columns? see another csv file has 5 columns.

```
OLEID,FROM,TO,ZON,PROS
07WJ05,0,125,ARCN,ABC
DDH006,891.68,7854,BASE,DEF
DD1,25687,15987,GOOD,NEM
```

My Code:

```
import os
   
def prepend_multiple_lines(file_name, list_of_lines):
    # define name of temporary dummy file
    dummy_file = file_name + '.csv'
    # open given original file in read mode and dummy file in write mode
    with open(file_name, 'r') as read_obj, open(dummy_file, 'w') as write_obj:
        # Iterate over the given list of strings and write them to dummy file as lines
        for line in list_of_lines:
            write_obj.write(line + '\n')
        # Read lines from original file one by one and append them to the dummy file
        for line in read_obj:
            write_obj.write(line)
    # remove original file
    os.remove(file_name)
    # Rename dummy file as the original file
    os.rename(dummy_file, file_name)
    
def main():
    print('*** Insert multiple lines from the second position of a file ***')
    list_of_lines = ['AA','AA','AA','AA','AA','AA','AA','AA','AA'] #add 9 AA constant value
    prepend_multiple_lines("DB_1.csv", list_of_lines)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

The problem with this code is that it is adding a constant value to only first column and ignoring all other column. Also, it is adding before header.

I also tried the insert way but it did not work:

```
with open(r"db_1.csv", "r") as f:
     contents = f.readlines()
     contents.insert(2, 'AAA')

with open(r"db_1.csv", "w") as f:
    contents = "".join(contents)
    f.write(contents)
```

CSV Files attached [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tCCp0dQwJVd9t0vZWZrhdGHAK_QE9jK4?usp=sharing)

Any help???

Comment: Those are not CSV files.  The "C" means "comma".  They are text files.  Are the columns separated by spaces, or by tabs?  Doing what you described is just brute force.  Read one line, write it.  Write your insert.  Read the rest of the file and write it.  You don't even need to use lines to copy the rest of the file.

Comment: I edit my questions. Now it looks like a CSV file. Also I have attached the CSV file. I also tried the insert way but it didn't work.

Comment: @tdelaney, no it is not a txt file. It is my mistake I loaded the file in the wrong format. The file is separated by comma. Also I attach google drive link to download those files.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `csv` module, otherwise you'll have plenty of issues parsing it including multiline and others:

```
import csv
import itertools
import os

def add_placeholder_to_csv(csv_reader, csv_writer,
                           cell_placeholder, start_row, end_row):
    # end_row is inclusive
    headers = next(csv_reader)
    cells_per_row = len(headers)
    csv_writer.writerow(headers)

    # Write everything until placeholder (-1 for header)
    csv_writer.writerows(itertools.islice(csv_reader, start_row-1))
    
    # Add placeholder
    csv_writer.writerows(
        [[cell_placeholder] * cells_per_row] * (end_row - start_row + 1))

    # Write everything after placeholder
    csv_writer.writerows(csv_reader)


with (open("mycsv.csv", newline="") as inputfile,
    open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as outputfile):
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile)
    writer = csv.writer(outputfile)
    add_placeholder_to_csv(reader, writer, "AA", 1, 7)

os.remove("mycsv.csv")
os.rename("output.csv", "mycsv.csv")
```